# Navision - Pass record field name dyanmically to function

Tags: erp, seaside, navision

I don't know whether any out there uses Navision?! but we've recently been lumbered with it and I'm trying to pass a field name dynamically to a function.

Instead of

```
ModelRec.SETCURRENTKEY(ModelRec.Transmission);
```

I want to do something like ...

```
ModelRec.SETCURRENTKEY(ModelRec("FieldName"));
```

where the string FieldName = "Transmission"

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write a little more code. In you function, you can say

```
CASE varFieldname Of
  Rec.FIELDNAME(FieldName1):
    Rec.SETCURRENTKEY(Fieldset1);
  Rec.FIELDNAME(FieldName2):
    Rec.SETCURRENTKEY(Fieldset2);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use: `Record.FIELDCAPTION(Field)`. This will return the name of your field.